# Why is my jQuery SlideDown animations Laggy/Jumpy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have been trying to implement the SlideDown animation to show a div when another div is clicked on.

I have come across many issues which are now sorted, but the main issue is that the jQuery animation is very **Laggy and Jumpy**

Is there anything I can do to smoothen the animations? I read about an easing plugin - do they help?

**Code Here: http://www.bootply.com/a8pRzgsjtl**

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".virus").click(function() {
                    $(".v").siblings().hide();
                    $(".information").slideDown(2000);
                    $(".v").fadeIn('slow');
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 1000)

                });

                 $(".screenRepair").click(function() { 
                    $(".screenInfo").siblings().hide();
                    $(".information").slideDown(2000);
                    $(".screenInfo").fadeIn(1000);
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 1000);
                });

                $(".SoftwareRepair").click(function() {
                    $(".softwareR").siblings().hide();
                    $(".information").slideDown('slow');
                    $(".softwareR").fadeIn('slow');
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 1000);
                });

                $(".MemoryUpgrades").click(function() {

                    $(".MemoryInfo").siblings().hide();
                    $(".information").slideDown("slow");
                    $(".MemoryInfo").fadeIn('slow');           
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 1000);
                });

                $(".hardwareRepair").click(function() {
                    $(".hardwareInfo").siblings().hide();
                    $(".information").slideDown('slow');
                    $(".hardwareInfo").fadeIn("slow");
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 1000);
                });

                $(".WindowsReinstall").click(function() {
                    $(".WindowsInfo").siblings().hide();
                    $(".information").slideDown("slow");
                    $(".WindowsInfo").fadeIn("slow");
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 1000);
                });

                $(".DataRecovery").click(function() {
                    $(".dataInfo").siblings().hide();
                    $('.information').slideDown('slow');
                    $(".dataInfo").fadeIn("slow");
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 1000);
                });

                $(".maintenance").click(function() {
                    $(".maintenanceInfo").siblings().hide();
                    $('.information').slideDown('slow');
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:200}, 1000);
                    $(".maintenanceInfo").fadeIn("slow");
                });

                $("#close").click(function() {
                    $(".information").slideUp('slow');
                });


            });
```

Comment: Everything looks good here on chrome running on a first-gen i5 processor with 4 gb ddr3 ram and a $15 graphics card... Maybe you got some memory leak or anything else slowing down your PC? :)

Answer (score 0):

A common issue is with images, if your elements contains or have images background make sure they are not too heavy...